# Cc# SQL query update when table changes?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Is there any way to make a ms sql table send out info each time the table has changed ?
I want the title of a ToolStripMenuItem to change each time someone inserts values to a table.

I've made a timer that updates each x seconds, but it would be better if it updated only when the sql table had changed.

My code:

```
//Rexton ordre klar til bestilling
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) from bestillinger WHERE firma = @rexton and udlevering BETWEEN @date and @dateadd";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bernafon", "Bernafon");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gn_resound", "GN Resound");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oticon", "Oticon");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonak", "Phonak");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rexton", "Rexton");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@siemens", "Siemens");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@widex", "Widex");

con.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
string result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

con.Close();

if (result != "0")
{
    rextonToolStripMenuItem.Text = "rexton " + result;
    rextonToolStripMenuItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF1919");
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter Why not post your comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SqlDependency` class and subscribe your handler method for change event

here is the msdn link  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx

```
SqlDependency sqlDep=new SqlDependency(SqlCommand);

sqlDep.OnChange+=new
   OnChangeEventHandler(OnChangeEventHandler);
```

Comment: When you copy-paste code from somewhere, it's better to cite your sources. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx